# Excel VBA FOR LOOP Crashing on 1000th Time

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use some VBA code to copy a range of cells and paste its values in the next empty rows 2111 times.

This pastes successfully up to the 754507 row where after this it crashes.

I can see in the debug that it stops at the 1000th loop.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Paste_APIROWS()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Long
Range("A2:H754").Copy
For i = 1 To 2111
    Range("A2:H754" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Debug.Print i
    Next i

   Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

I expect in the end to have about 1589583 rows but instead appear to be only getting about half of this.

> The error message I get is "Run-time error '1004':  Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed"

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean `Range("A2:H" & CStr(754+i)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`

Answer (score 4):

Run the loop in your head:

1. When `i = 1`, then the range is `"A2:H7541"` (Rows `2` through `7,541`)
2. When `i = 2`, then the range is `"A2:H7542"` (Rows `2` through `7,542`)
3. When `i = 9`, then the range is `"A2:H7549"` (Rows `2` through `7,549`)
4. When `i = 10`, then the range is `"A2:H75410"` (Rows `2` through `75,410`)
5. When `i = 99`, then the range is `"A2:H75499"` (Rows `2` through `75,499`)
6. When `i = 100`, then the range is `"A2:H754100"` (Rows `2` through `754,100`)
7. When `i = 900`, then the range is `"A2:H754900"` (Rows `2` through `754,900`)
8. When `i = 999`, then the range is `"A2:H754999"` (Rows `2` through `754,999`)
9. When `i = 1000`, then the range is `"A2:H7541000"` (Rows `2` through `7,541,000`)

Notice as each value of `i` crosses each 10th power the row number increases by an order of magnitude:

- From `i = 9` to `i = 10` you go from row `7,549` to `75,410`
- From `i = 99` to `i = 100` you go from row `75,499` to `754,100`
- From `i = 999` to `i = 1000` you go from row `754,100` to `7,541,000`

Also note that your destination range row is always `2` - so on each iteration you're always overwriting yourself.

It crashes because Excel spreadsheets (since Excel 2007) cannot exceed `1,048,576` rows, hence the crash. The limit is `65,355` prior to Excel 2007 or when using a non-OOXML spreadsheet in modern versions of Excel).

> I expect in the end to have about `1,589,583` rows but instead appear to be only getting about half of this.

Two things:

- Excel does not support `1,589,583` rows anyway (as said, the maximum is `1,048,576`).
- Your logic does not compute copy destination ranges correctly, as per my explanation above.

The cause of your bug is the use of string concatenation (i.e. the `&` operator) instead of numerical addition.

You want to copy cells in the range `A2:H754` some <del>2111</del> 1930 times - that means you actually want to do this:

```
Const sourceRowLB =   2
Const sourceRowUB = 755 ' 755 not 754 because exclusive upper-bounds are easier to work with
Dim sourceRowCount = sourceRowUB - sourceRowLB

Dim lastCopyUB = 755

Dim sourceRangeExpr = GetRangeExpr( "A", sourceRowLB, "H", sourceRowUB ) ' Will be "A2:H754"
Range( sourceRangeExpr  ).Copy

Const loopCount As Integer = 1389 ' This cannot be 2111 because ( 2111 * 754 ) exceeds the maximum row count
For i = 1 ToloopCount ' Loop 1389 times

    ' Recompute the destination range:
    Dim destRowLB As Integer
    destRowLB = lastCopyUB
    Dim destRowUB As Integer
    destRowUB = destRowLB + sourceRowCount

    Dim rangeExpression As String
    rangeExpression = GetRangeExpr( "A", destRowLB, "H" & destRowUB )

    Range( rangeExpression ).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    lastCopyUB = destRowUB

Next i

Function GetRangeExpr(startCol As String, startRow As Integer, endCol As String, endRowExclUB As Integer) As String

    GetRangeExpr = startCol  & CStr( destRowLB ) & ":" & endCol & CStr( endRowExclUB  - 1 ) ' We convert endRowExclUB to an inclusive upper-bound here

End Function
```

Comment: @chrisneilsen derp! thank you for pointing that out. I've rewritten my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints:

1. There is no need to do string math like `Range("A2:H754" & i)`. A better solution is starting from the top left cell use `.Cells(row, column)` method to access a specific cell.
2. Expand a cell into a table using the `.Resize(row_count, column_count)` method.
3. Finally, there is no need to use the clipboard with the `.Copy` or `.Paste` methods are this is slow and memory intensive. Use direct assignment into the `.Value` property.

For example, to copy the 178th row from a table of 1000×8 cells located under `A2` into the first row of the sheet, use the following

```
Range("A1").Resize(1,8).Value = Range("A2").Cells(178,1).Resize(1,8).Value
```

Note that the `.Resize()` values *much match* on both sides of the assignment.